# Storyboard on DataTrigger not firing correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to create a "drop down" animation for a custom menu using a `Storyboard` on a `StackPanel`.  I am using a `DataTrigger` on a boolean in my ViewModel (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) to actually fire the `BeginStoryboard`.  Currently, one of the `Storyboard`s fires (on `Value="False"`), but the other does not.  Sample code below.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Command="{Binding TogglePanelVisibleCommand}"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPanelVisible}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="350" Duration="0:0:0.45" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPanelVisible}" Value="False">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="350" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.45" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <Button Content="Button 1"/>
        <Button Content="Button 2"/>
        <Button Content="Button 3"/>
        <Button Content="Button 4"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Basically, I want the top button to toggle the drop down action when pressed.  The command just toggles the bit in the code behind.  I need the boolean to be in the code behind so that I can also toggle the menu from other UI elements of from ViewModel code.

Does anyone know why only one of the `Storyboard`s is actually getting run?

EDIT: For the curious, here is the implementation of the command and ViewModel boolean.

```
private bool _IsPanelVisible = false;
public bool IsPanelVisible
{
    get { return this._IsPanelVisible; }
    set
    {
         this._IsPanelVisible = value;
         this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsPanelVisible"));
    }
}

public ICommand TogglePanelVisibleCommand = new RelayCommand(o => this.IsPanelVisible = !this.IsPanelVisible);
```

Comment: Can you post your `TogglePanelVisibleCommand`, and the `IsPanelVisible` implementation?

Comment: Stupid question, can't you just use DataTrigger.ExitActions to remove the storyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try using this?

```
<DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard Name="OpenDropDown">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="350" Duration="0:0:0.45" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</DataTrigger.EnterActions>
<DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenDropDown" />
</DataTrigger.ExitActions>
```

Comment: This did the trick.  I did not know you needed to remove the `Storyboard` if you are not using a `RepeatBehavior`.  Can you explain why this is necessary?  Can only a single `Storyboard` be active at one time?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx The default value for FillBehavior is HoldEnd so the animation is valid until you remove it.

Comment: For remembering `RemoveStoryboard` +1

Comment: Oh and if you *want* to have the animation on closing, then you can do something with HandoffBehavior=Compose. Maybe using the same trigger but 2 storyboards.

Comment: I'd imagine StopStoryboard would work as well. Do you know when to prefer Remove over Stop or vice versa?

Comment: Remove will also free up the resources taken up by the storyboard, stopping will keep those references. So it really depends on the situation.